# Usual example of dash Multi-Page Apps and URL Support shows an empty page

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to run the example provide by the Dash website to make a Multi-Page Apps. It shows on my browser an empty page

I have tried on different browser, I just copied a paste the code nothing else

https://dash.plot.ly/urls

The pqages are empty for any example in this page

Comment: I just tried running the example, and it worked fine for me. Are you seeing any errors in your Python console, or in the browser console?

Comment: Not at all, just the sign "\" at the begining of the page

Comment: There is no errors in the console

Comment: What are you using the run the Python code? IDLE? Which URL are you using to visit the page? Are the packages all up to date? Which version of Python are you using? What OS is this happening on?